# Is it possible in HTL/Sightly to open or close tag conditionally?

Tags: aem, sightly

I'm new to AEM, so any advice is appreciated.

Let's say I've something like this:

```
<div class="big-item" data-sly-list="${features.list}">
     
     <sly data-sly-test="${ itemList.first || itemList.count == 5 || itemList.count == 9 || itemList.count == 13 || itemList.count == 17 }">
         <div class="small-item-wrapper>
             <div class="additional-div">
     </sly>

            <div class="small-item">
                <div>${item.somecontent}</div>
            </div>

     <sly data-sly-test="${ itemList.last || itemList.count == "4 || itemList.count == 8 || itemList.count == 12 || itemList.count == 16 }">               
            </div>   
            </div>  
      </sly>

</div>
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to wrap every 4 items in a separate container.

For now, the closing tag isn't rendered or rather is closed only after the last iteration.

Is such an html-templating approach doable in AEM? Can I do this purely in htl?
Currently, this does not work for me, I suppose there's some automation going on which I'm not aware of.

How can I do this?

PS. When the structure is simple (no nested divs) seems to be working, when subdivs are added it starts to break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not allowed as the HTL script should be a valid HTML (hence no unfinished/conditional tags). There are a few workaround though. Let's assume your items look like (JS use-object that can be tested with [HTL REPL](https://github.com/adobe/aem-htl-repl)):

```
use(function () {
    return {
        list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    };
});
```

You could then render them with this HTL script:

```
<div class="big-item" data-sly-use.logic="logic.js">
    <div class="small-item-wrapper" data-sly-test="${logic.list.length > 0}">
        <div class="additional-div">
            <div class="small-item" data-sly-repeat="${logic.list @ begin=0, end=3}">
                <div>${item}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="small-item-wrapper" data-sly-test="${logic.list.length > 4}">
        <div class="additional-div">
            <div class="small-item" data-sly-repeat="${logic.list @ begin=4, end=7}">
                <div>${item}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="small-item-wrapper" data-sly-test="${logic.list.length > 8}">
        <div class="additional-div">
            <div class="small-item" data-sly-repeat="${logic.list @ begin=8, end=11}">
                <div>${item}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="small-item-wrapper" data-sly-test="${logic.list.length > 12}">
        <div class="additional-div">
            <div class="small-item" data-sly-repeat="${logic.list @ begin=12, end=15}">
                <div>${item}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's ugly and hardcoded up to 16 items but should work.

If you can "massage" the data ahead of time you could prepare a set of [`begin`, `end`] markers and make the HTL script nicer. Here's the use-object:

```
use(function () {
    let list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17];
    let markers = [];
    for (let i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        if (i % 4 === 0) {
            markers.push([i, i+3]);
        }
    }
    return {
        markers: markers,
        list: list
    };
});
```

and corresponding HTL script:

```
<div class="big-item">
    <div class="small-item-wrapper" data-sly-repeat.marker="${logic.markers}">
        <div class="additional-div">
            <div class="small-item" data-sly-repeat="${logic.list @ begin=marker[0], end=marker[1]}">
                <div>${item}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, much obliged. So it seems to me the best way to deal with this would be remodel data in dialog itself. Thank you for thorough explanation, didn't know about js logic snippets usage.